# Sending Push Notifications to Multiple Students Using React, Nest.js, and Socket.IO and rabbitMQ

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, rabbitmq, nestjs

I need to send push notifications to multiple students using React on the frontend and Nest.js with Socket.IO and RabbitMQ on the backend. Here's a breakdown of the steps I've taken so far:

1. The frontend client sends a notification message to a microservice.
2. The microservice publishes this message to a RabbitMQ queue.
3. The email service consumes the message from RabbitMQ.

Now, I want to extend this process to send push notifications to the students mentioned in the message. I have the student IDs included in the `"receiver_info"` array within the message. The frontend uses Socket.IO to listen for notifications.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I use Nest.js and Socket.IO to efficiently send the push notifications to the specified students based on the `"receiver_info"` array?
2. Do I need to establish a separate Socket.IO connection for each student's frontend client, or is there a more scalable way to achieve this?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

#### Rabbitmq

**Message Consumer:**

{
"profile_id": "b5882844-addc-4fe7-857f-f4812796a9d2",
"message_id": "e3a6f9d0-28ea-4e53-9bbb-1c676aedf73c",
"date_time": "2023-08-27T17:23:47.214Z",
"is_group_message": 0,
"attachment_details": [
{
"size": 798806,
"fileId": "909f68d8-7c1b-4e28-b739-c9c2f0446a42.jpg",
"filename": "nature-2742751.jpg",
"mimetype": "image/jpeg"
}
],
"has_attachments": 0,
"is_important": 1,
"message": "bbbbbbbbbbbb",
"receiver_info": [
"master@isl",
"deepika@wbs",
"admin@vp",
"shourie@wbs"
],
"subject": "Check the images!"
}

this is the message I am consuming for rabbitmq.

#### Backend (Nest.js)

```
@SubscribeMessage('findAllNotifications')
  async findAll(client: Socket) {
    const response = await this.notificationsService.findAll();
    console.log(response)

    const studentIds: string[] = ['master@isl','admin@klu']; // Array of student IDs
    const notificationData: any = "Hello I am working"; // Notification data

    studentIds.forEach(studentId => {
      // Emit a notification event to each student
      this.server.to(studentId).emit('notification', notificationData);
    });
   }
```

Frontend (React)
Socket.IO Setup:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:5092");
      console.log(socket);
      setAuth((a) => ({ ...a, socket }));

      
      socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to server');
        socket.emit('findAllNotifications'); 
      });


      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("disconnected");
      });

      socket.on('notification',(notificationData) => {
        // Handle the received notification here
        console.log('Received notification:', notificationData);
      })
```